# Graphics2D and user movement setup

Tags: java, actionlistener, keylistener

I am testing out graphics movement with simple action and key listener commands, but am struggling to incorporate the Graphics2D class. I am looking to draw an ellipse, which is then controllable through the use of the up, down, left and right keys. I am struggling to put all this together as i am very knew to a lot of this and followed a very outdated guide, as I could not find anything recent. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code below:

````
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
public class Screen extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {  

Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
int x = 0, y = 0, velx = 0, vely = 0;

   public Screen() {
   t.start();
   addKeyListener(this);
   setFocusable(true);
   }
      
      
     
   
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
   {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      GRAPHICS2D g2 = (GRAPHICS2D) g;
      g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40));
   }
   
   public void actionPeformed(ActionEvent e) {
   repaint();
   x += velx;
   y += vely;
   }
   public void up() {
   vely = -1.5;
   velx = 0;
   }
   public void down(); {
   vely = 1.5;
   velx = 0;
   }
   public void left(); {
   vely = 0;
   velx = -1.5;
   }
   public void right(); {
   vely = 0;
   velx = 1.5;
   }
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
      int code = e.getKeyCode();
      
      if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
         up();
      }
      if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
         down();
      }
      if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
         left();
      }
      if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
         right();
      }
   }
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
 }```
When ran, it gives an error saying it cannot find a symbol when drawing the Ellipse, as well as giving missing method body errors for all of the movement calls. Help would be appreciated!
````

Comment: There is no `GRAPHICS2D` class. It's `Graphics2D`

Answer (score 0):

You will want to become familiar with [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and [actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) it is going to seriously make your life simpler in the long run.

The following example is deliberately long winded, as it's intended to demonstrate the power of the `Action` API.

So, I started with a concept of "direction"

```
public enum Direction {
    UP, DOWN,
    LEFT, RIGHT;
}
```

This is what's going to be supported, in terms of movements.

I then setup a basic "direction action", which will add or remove a `Direction` to a `Set`.  Through this workflow, the "main loop" will decide what to do based on what's in the `Set`

```
public class InputAction extends AbstractAction {
    
    private Direction input;
    private Set<Direction> manager;
    private boolean release;

    public InputAction(Direction input, Set<Direction> manager, boolean release) {
        this.input = input;
        this.manager = manager;
        this.release = release;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (release) {
            manager.remove(input);
        } else {
            manager.add(input);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Because it can become really confusing really fast, I created a "pressed" and "released" `InputAction`

```
public class InputPressedAction extends InputAction {

    public InputPressedAction(Direction input, Set<Direction> manager) {
        super(input, manager, false);
    }
    
}

public class InputReleasedAction extends InputAction {

    public InputReleasedAction(Direction input, Set<Direction> manager) {
        super(input, manager, true);
    }
    
}
```

Following from that, I created specific direction actions, again, to make it simpler to configure.

```
public class UpPressedAction extends InputPressedAction {

    public UpPressedAction(Set<Direction> manager) {
        super(Direction.UP, manager);
    }
    
}

public class UpReleasedAction extends InputReleasedAction {

    public UpReleasedAction(Set<Direction> manager) {
        super(Direction.UP, manager);
    }
    
}

public class DownPressedAction extends InputPressedAction {

    public DownPressedAction(Set<Direction> manager) {
        super(Direction.DOWN, manager);
    }
    
}

public class DownReleasedAction extends InputReleasedAction {

    public DownReleasedAction(Set<Direction> manager) {
        super(Direction.DOWN, manager);
    }
    
}
    
public class LeftPressedAction extends InputPressedAction {

    public LeftPressedAction(Set<Direction> manager) {
        super(Direction.LEFT, manager);
    }
    
}

public class LeftReleasedAction extends InputReleasedAction {

    public LeftReleasedAction(Set<Direction> manager) {
        super(Direction.LEFT, manager);
    }
    
}
    
public class RightPressedAction extends InputPressedAction {

    public RightPressedAction(Set<Direction> manager) {
        super(Direction.RIGHT, manager);
    }
    
}

public class RightReleasedAction extends InputReleasedAction {

    public RightReleasedAction(Set<Direction> manager) {
        super(Direction.RIGHT, manager);
    }
    
}
```

Next, I setup the key bindings...

```
InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false), ActionKey.UP_PRESSED);
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true), ActionKey.UP_RELEASED);
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false), ActionKey.DOWN_PRESSED);
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), ActionKey.DOWN_RELEASED);
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), ActionKey.LEFT_PRESSED);
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), ActionKey.LEFT_RELEASED);
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), ActionKey.RIGHT_PRESSED);
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), ActionKey.RIGHT_RELEASED);

actionMap.put(ActionKey.UP_PRESSED, new UpPressedAction(actions));
actionMap.put(ActionKey.UP_RELEASED, new UpReleasedAction(actions));
actionMap.put(ActionKey.DOWN_PRESSED, new DownPressedAction(actions));
actionMap.put(ActionKey.DOWN_RELEASED, new DownReleasedAction(actions));
actionMap.put(ActionKey.LEFT_PRESSED, new LeftPressedAction(actions));
actionMap.put(ActionKey.LEFT_RELEASED, new LeftReleasedAction(actions));
actionMap.put(ActionKey.RIGHT_PRESSED, new RightPressedAction(actions));
actionMap.put(ActionKey.RIGHT_RELEASED, new RightReleasedAction(actions));
```

And you can start to see why I created all those action classes.

Then the "main" loop just needs to inspect the state of the `Set` and make determinations about what it should do...

```
timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (actions.contains(Direction.UP)) {
            YPos -= 1;
        }
        if (actions.contains(Direction.DOWN)) {
            YPos += 1;
        }

        if (actions.contains(Direction.LEFT)) {
            xPos -= 1;
        }
        if (actions.contains(Direction.RIGHT)) {
            xPos += 1;
        }

        if (YPos < 0) {
            YPos = 0;
        } else if (YPos > getHeight() - shape.getBounds().height) {
            YPos = getHeight() - shape.getBounds().height;
        }

        if (xPos < 0) {
            xPos = 0;
        } else if (xPos > getWidth() - shape.getBounds().width) {
            xPos = getWidth() - shape.getBounds().width;
        }
        repaint();
    }
});
```

And painting becomes as simple as moving the shape...

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2d.translate(xPos, YPos);
    g2d.fill(shape);
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

## Runnable Example

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public enum Direction {
        UP, DOWN,
        LEFT, RIGHT;
    }

    public class InputAction extends AbstractAction {

        private Direction input;
        private Set<Direction> manager;
        private boolean release;

        public InputAction(Direction input, Set<Direction> manager, boolean release) {
            this.input = input;
            this.manager = manager;
            this.release = release;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (release) {
                manager.remove(input);
            } else {
                manager.add(input);
            }
        }

    }

    public class InputPressedAction extends InputAction {

        public InputPressedAction(Direction input, Set<Direction> manager) {
            super(input, manager, false);
        }

    }

    public class InputReleasedAction extends InputAction {

        public InputReleasedAction(Direction input, Set<Direction> manager) {
            super(input, manager, true);
        }

    }

    public class UpPressedAction extends InputPressedAction {

        public UpPressedAction(Set<Direction> manager) {
            super(Direction.UP, manager);
        }

    }

    public class UpReleasedAction extends InputReleasedAction {

        public UpReleasedAction(Set<Direction> manager) {
            super(Direction.UP, manager);
        }

    }

    public class DownPressedAction extends InputPressedAction {

        public DownPressedAction(Set<Direction> manager) {
            super(Direction.DOWN, manager);
        }

    }

    public class DownReleasedAction extends InputReleasedAction {

        public DownReleasedAction(Set<Direction> manager) {
            super(Direction.DOWN, manager);
        }

    }

    public class LeftPressedAction extends InputPressedAction {

        public LeftPressedAction(Set<Direction> manager) {
            super(Direction.LEFT, manager);
        }

    }

    public class LeftReleasedAction extends InputReleasedAction {

        public LeftReleasedAction(Set<Direction> manager) {
            super(Direction.LEFT, manager);
        }

    }

    public class RightPressedAction extends InputPressedAction {

        public RightPressedAction(Set<Direction> manager) {
            super(Direction.RIGHT, manager);
        }

    }

    public class RightReleasedAction extends InputReleasedAction {

        public RightReleasedAction(Set<Direction> manager) {
            super(Direction.RIGHT, manager);
        }

    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        enum ActionKey {
            UP_PRESSED,
            UP_RELEASED,
            DOWN_PRESSED,
            DOWN_RELEASED,
            LEFT_PRESSED,
            LEFT_RELEASED,
            RIGHT_PRESSED,
            RIGHT_RELEASED;
        }

        private Set<Direction> actions = new HashSet<>();
        private Timer timer;

        private Shape shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 40, 40);
        int YPos = 0;
        int xPos = 100 - 20;

        public TestPane() {
            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false), ActionKey.UP_PRESSED);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true), ActionKey.UP_RELEASED);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false), ActionKey.DOWN_PRESSED);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), ActionKey.DOWN_RELEASED);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), ActionKey.LEFT_PRESSED);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), ActionKey.LEFT_RELEASED);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), ActionKey.RIGHT_PRESSED);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), ActionKey.RIGHT_RELEASED);

            actionMap.put(ActionKey.UP_PRESSED, new UpPressedAction(actions));
            actionMap.put(ActionKey.UP_RELEASED, new UpReleasedAction(actions));
            actionMap.put(ActionKey.DOWN_PRESSED, new DownPressedAction(actions));
            actionMap.put(ActionKey.DOWN_RELEASED, new DownReleasedAction(actions));
            actionMap.put(ActionKey.LEFT_PRESSED, new LeftPressedAction(actions));
            actionMap.put(ActionKey.LEFT_RELEASED, new LeftReleasedAction(actions));
            actionMap.put(ActionKey.RIGHT_PRESSED, new RightPressedAction(actions));
            actionMap.put(ActionKey.RIGHT_RELEASED, new RightReleasedAction(actions));

            timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (actions.contains(Direction.UP)) {
                        YPos -= 1;
                    }
                    if (actions.contains(Direction.DOWN)) {
                        YPos += 1;
                    }

                    if (actions.contains(Direction.LEFT)) {
                        xPos -= 1;
                    }
                    if (actions.contains(Direction.RIGHT)) {
                        xPos += 1;
                    }

                    if (YPos < 0) {
                        YPos = 0;
                    } else if (YPos > getHeight() - shape.getBounds().height) {
                        YPos = getHeight() - shape.getBounds().height;
                    }

                    if (xPos < 0) {
                        xPos = 0;
                    } else if (xPos > getWidth() - shape.getBounds().width) {
                        xPos = getWidth() - shape.getBounds().width;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            timer.stop();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.translate(xPos, YPos);
            g2d.fill(shape);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

## Why not use a `KeyListener`

If you spend anytime researching the problem, you will find that, often (too often), `KeyListener` is "recommend" to monitor key input.  Also, probably more often, you come across a number of issues related to the use of `KeyListener`, especially in this role.

`KeyListener` needs the component it's registered to be focusable AND have current focus before it will react to the user input.

The above solution also overcomes a OS limitation, where, when a key is first pressed, there is a short delay between the first and repeating keys.  Instead, the above solution simply raises a flag when the key is pressed and removes it when it's released - simple, but effective

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

MadProgrammer focused on Key Listeners in his answer.  I want to focus on the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern and code organization.

Here's the GUI I came up with.

[image: Circle Movement]

I use Key Bindings, so the arrow keys and the WASD keys move the circle.  MadProgrammer explained it in his answer, so I won't repeat his explanation.  As his key bindings do, mine move the circle at a steady pace as long as you're holding one of the keys down.  Release the key, and the circle stops moving.

## Explanation

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), that will show you the basics of Swing.  Skip the Netbeans section.

In the MVC pattern, you create the model first, then the view, then the controllers.  There's usually not one controller to rule them all.  Each `ActionListener` acts independently, controlling its portion of the view and the model.

### Model

The first thing I did was create the application model.  I created two classes, `CircleMovementModel` and `Circle`.  Both are plain Java getter / setter classes.  The `Circle` class holds the components to draw a circle.  The `CircleMovementModel` holds a `Circle` instance, the width, and the height of the drawing `JPanel`.

### View

I started the Swing application with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I created the `JFrame` and the drawing `JPanel` in separate classes.  The `JFrame` has a default [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html), which I used.  I separate the creation of the `JFrame` and all associated `JPanels` into separate methods and classes so it's easier for human readers to understand the code.

The `JFrame` methods must be called in a specific order.  This is the order I use for my Swing applications.

The drawing `JPanel` draws the circle in the specified position.  Period.  Nothing else.  The movement of the circle is handled in the Swing `Timer`.

### Controller

The key bindings look pretty complicated.  There's a set of key bindings when the key is pressed.  There's another set of key bindings when the key is released.  The one `Action` class, `MovementAction`, handles all of the movements by passing the appropriate `deltaX` and `deltaY` through the constructor.

Finally, the `ActionListener` of the Swing `Timer` class moves the `Circle` instance at a steady pace.  I made this class an anonymous class because it was so short.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the additional classes inner classes so I could post this code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class CircleMovementGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CircleMovementGUI());
    }
    
    private final CircleMovementModel model;
    
    private final DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    public CircleMovementGUI() {
        this.model = new CircleMovementModel();
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(model);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Circle Movement");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setKeyBindings(drawingPanel);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        Timer timer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                model.getCircle().incrementX();
                model.getCircle().incrementY();
                drawingPanel.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
    
    private void setKeyBindings(DrawingPanel drawingPanel) {
        InputMap inputMap = drawingPanel.getInputMap();
        ActionMap actionMap = drawingPanel.getActionMap();
        
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false), "up");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false), "down");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), "left");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), "right");
        
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), "up");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false), "down");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "left");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "right");
        
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true), "stop");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), "stop");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), "stop");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), "stop");
        
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true), "stop");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, true), "stop");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), "stop");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), "stop");
        
        actionMap.put("up", new MovementAction(model, 0.0, -1.5));
        actionMap.put("down", new MovementAction(model, 0.0, +1.5));
        actionMap.put("left", new MovementAction(model, -1.5, 0.0));
        actionMap.put("right", new MovementAction(model, +1.5, 0.0));
        actionMap.put("stop", new MovementAction(model, 0.0, 0.0));
    }
    
    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private final CircleMovementModel model;

        public DrawingPanel(CircleMovementModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(model.getDrawingPanelWidth(), 
                    model.getDrawingPanelHeight()));
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, 
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, 
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);

            Circle circle = model.getCircle();
            int radius = circle.getRadius();
            int diameter = radius + radius;
            double x = Math.round(circle.getX()) - radius;
            double y = Math.round(circle.getY()) - radius;
            
            g2d.setColor(circle.getColor());
            g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, diameter, diameter));
        }
        
    }
    
    public class MovementAction extends AbstractAction {
        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private final double deltaX, deltaY;
        
        private final CircleMovementModel model;

        public MovementAction(CircleMovementModel model, 
                double deltaX, double deltaY) {
            this.model = model;
            this.deltaX = deltaX;
            this.deltaY = deltaY;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            model.getCircle().setDeltaX(deltaX);
            model.getCircle().setDeltaY(deltaY);
        }
        
    }
    
    public class CircleMovementModel {
        
        private final int drawingPanelWidth, drawingPanelHeight;
        
        private final Circle circle;
        
        public CircleMovementModel() {
            this.drawingPanelWidth = 600;
            this.drawingPanelHeight = drawingPanelWidth;
            this.circle = new Circle(Color.YELLOW, 20, drawingPanelWidth / 2, 
                    drawingPanelHeight / 2);
        }

        public int getDrawingPanelWidth() {
            return drawingPanelWidth;
        }

        public int getDrawingPanelHeight() {
            return drawingPanelHeight;
        }

        public Circle getCircle() {
            return circle;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Circle {
        
        private final int radius;
        
        private double x, y, deltaX, deltaY;
        
        private final Color color;
        
        public Circle(Color color, int radius, int x, int y) {
            this.color = color;
            this.radius = radius;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.deltaX = 0.0;
            this.deltaY = 0.0;
        }

        public double getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public void incrementX() {
            this.x = x + deltaX;
        }

        public double getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void incrementY() {
            this.y = y + deltaY;
        }

        public double getDeltaX() {
            return deltaX;
        }

        public void setDeltaX(double deltaX) {
            this.deltaX = deltaX;
        }

        public double getDeltaY() {
            return deltaY;
        }

        public void setDeltaY(double deltaY) {
            this.deltaY = deltaY;
        }

        public int getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }
        
    }

}
```